# Golang Docker API: get events

Tags: docker, go, docker-api

I want to get all new events from docker via the golang integration.
The problem is that it returns two channels and I couldn't figure out how to subscribe to them.

```
cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.WithVersion("1.37"))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

ctx, _ := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

msg, err := <- cli.Events(ctx, types.EventsOptions{})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many solutions. A solution could be:

```
msgs, errs := cli.Events(ctx, types.EventsOptions{})

for {
        select {
          case err := <-errs:print(err)
          case msg := <-msgs:print(msg)
        }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just had to remove the `<-`  right before `cli.Events(ctx, types.EventsOptions{})`